# Getting a single value from an indexed array

Tags: php

good morning,
i need some help. am using mysql_fetch_row(), which gets a single record from a result set as an indexed array (one that refers to elements by numbers). but i cant get any value passed into my variable

```
//get the total number of images
$getTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images";
$total = mysql_query($getTotal); 
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($total);
$totalPix = $rows[0];
```

am trying to get an element or single recored passed into my variable totalPix, is there any other way of achieving this. 
thanks you

Comment: Your question says you're using `mysql_fetch_row`, but your code uses `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Those are different functions that have different results. You might want to look up the differences.

Comment: **associative array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to

```
$getTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM images";
```

and

```
$totalPix = $rows['Total'];
```

since you are using [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) that returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row.

Also you should move to mysqli or PDO

mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: [choosing an API guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: thanks guys, i just used a field name as suggested. am still very new to PHP & this forum. i appreciate you bring PDO to my attention i will certainly do as advised

Answer (score 1):

Your `$rows` is going to contain an array of fields returned, even if it's just COUNT(*).

Try:

```
$totalPix = $rows['COUNT(*)'];
```

... or name your `COUNT` in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount FROM images
...
$totalPix = $rows['totalcount'];
```

--edit-- removed 0 from assoc array return

Comment: Why the [0]? Associative arrays don't use numerals unless I'm deadly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, an associative array isn't numeric. So using the `0` index won't work.

You'll want to use `$rows['COUNT(*)']` since you're using that query.